# How to Render Content of CALayer on a Background Thread

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer

I am implementing a CALayer that needs to perform drawing on the background thread. However, despite setting the property "drawsAsynchronously" to true, the draw function is still being called on the main thread. Here's my current implementation:

```
class DKVectorLayer : CALayer {
    private let renderQueue = DispatchQueue( label: "Render queue, qos: .userInitiated)

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        // This is still running in the main thread
    }
}
```

I attempted to move the rendering code to a background queue using "renderQueue.async", but it doesn't seem to work as expected. It appears that the drawing code executed inside the "renderQueue.async" closure is ignored, and the drawing occurs after the "draw(in:)" function.

```
override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
    renderQueue.async {
        // Render code here, but it does not display on the screen
    }
}
```

Is there any way to render the content of a CALayer on a background thread? I am aware that CATiledLayer can render contents on a background thread, but it has some limitations. For example, when calling "setNeedsDisplay(in: rect)", the specified rectangle is ignored, and all tiles are redrawn.

Comment: *"... a CALayer that needs to perform drawing on the main thread"* is a little ambiguous. You can use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` on a background thread... We can offer help if you provide a minimal actual example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my fault, I meant "I am implementing a CALayer that needs to perform drawing on the background thread"

Comment: OK - still not clear though what you mean by *"needs to perform drawing"* ... can you provide a simple example of your CALayer drawing?

Comment: Sure, I will implement an example then post the link here, thank you!
I meant, the drawing code of the CALayer should be perform in background thread, I currently use the draw(in ctx) for that, but because I want to draw too many UIBezierPaths on the layer, and it could block the main thread for a second during the rendering. I want to move it to background thread to make the app more responsive

Comment: by "perform drawing" I mean rendering, just like what we do with rendering contents on UIVIew with drawRect(), but with CALayer

Answer (score 3):

When `draw(in:)` completes, the layer must be completely drawn. You cannot delay drawing by dispatching inside of `draw(in:)`. However, CALayer is thread-safe, and you are free to call `draw(in:)` on another thread and manage the layer drawing yourself. The result will be drawn into the CGContext you pass. You can also create a CGImage and assign it to the `content` property as long as this isn't a layer-backed view.

`drawsAsynchronously` does not determine where `draw(in:)` is executed. It determines where the final rendering occurs (turning the CGContext instructions into a bitmap). `draw(in:)` doesn't generate a bitmap. It just creates instructions.

If your layer is being rendered as part of a view hierarchy, it's going to happen on the thread the system chooses (this is often the main thread, but during animations it may not be). Typically what you do is compute everything expensive on a background thread and cache it, so when UIKit or AppKit asks to draw the layer, then it's fast.

Comment: The explanation you provided about the drawsAsynchronously property is accurate: it doesn't control the execution location of the draw(in:) method. One possible solution is to render the layer's content to an image on a background thread and then set the contents of the CALayer on the main thread. However, this approach has a drawback: it requires rendering the entire content of the CALayer, as there isn't a known method to selectively render and replace only a portion of the old image. On the other hand, the draw(in:) method only needs to render the content within the dirty rect

Comment: Typically the better solution to that would be to use multiple CALayers rather than trying to partially update one. CALayers are designed to be composed (it's one of their most compelling features). But you can definitely update a portion of contents by manipulating the CGImage bitmap (this is what the system is going to do with your drawing commands anyway; you can just manage that directly if you have specialized needs). But you are correct that it's nice to avoid directly manipulating the contents if you can. It opens up a number of headaches that are nice to avoid.